# Reading the tea leaves: continuing to monitor closing and deletion trends on the site

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions, data-explorer

I ran a [database query](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/649165/number-of-open-closed-and-deleted-questions-by-month#graph) again to see where we are a few months after the recent election. As I inspected the result I wondered if the number of posts deleted as a fraction of those closed was informative of the quality of votes cast to close posts. For instance, if these match closely (the fraction is close to unity), that indicates that most closed posts are eventually deleted and suggests to me that those close votes are a good decision, if "good" is interpreted to mean that the closed posts were unlikely to be rescued because of severe shortcomings in quality.

What is correct or flawed with this line of argumentation? What else can be inferred from this data regarding whether calls to close are achieving a positive outcome?

Feel free to also comment or suggest alternative queries or information that might be useful to disentangle this somewhat open question.

Comment: It is flawed. This query is very simple - doesn't really get into details. Some questions are closed only after being answered, which makes deletion less likely, for example.